# UK Settlement Visa with no return ticket

Tags: dependent-visa

My friend applied for a settlement visa, and luckily she got it!

Her husband resides in UK. She has resigned her job and has purchased a one way ticket to UK.

Now she's worried that she might get refused entry because she has no return ticket, or a job to go back to.

I told her, that the whole point that she applied for a settlement visa is to live with her husband and work in the UK.

So understandably she would leave her job, and fly to UK with only a one way ticket.

We have tried our best to rationalise but I hope you people could help since you have more clarity on this.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to document something that does not exist.

The official UK sites state that such visas are initially issued for 30 months

- **afterwhich** you are expected to have it **renewed**

**Conclusion:**

If they expect you to renew it

- they are **not** expecting you to leave

so an Immigration Officer would not expect you to have a return ticket

- they may even become **suspicious** if you did

---

Mayby this could serve as a **negative** proof.

Comment: Definitely makes sense. Thank you Mark!